# writing a tag after cleartimeout in js

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, cleartimeout

This is the code for countdown. After countdown I need to show a hyperlink
`<a id="hi" href="page.html">click</a>` to users.assuming Eventtime today or you can change it there. How can I do this?

Please correct this code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
  </head>
  <body>
            <p id="days" style="display:inline;">00</p> Days 
            <p id="hours" style="display: inline;">00</p> Hrs 
            <p id="minutes" style="display: inline;">00 </p> Min 
            <p id="seconds" style="display: inline;">00</p> seconds Left


            <div id="hi"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


            var timer;


        function myLoop() {

            var now = new Date();
            var eventDate = new Date(2017, 9, 21,7,56);

            var currentTime = now.getTime();
            var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

            var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

            var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
            var m = Math.floor(s/60);
            var h = Math.floor(m/60);
            var d = Math.floor(h/24);

            h %= 24;
            m %= 60;
            s %= 60;

            h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
            m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
            s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
                if(d>=0 && h>=0 && m>=0 && s>=0)
        {                   

            document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
            document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
            document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;


        if(d>=0 && h>=0 && m>=0 && s>=0)
            {
                timer= setTimeout(myLoop, 1000);

            }

            else
            {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
            document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML=
                               "<a id='hi'href='page.html'>click</a>";

            }

        }


    }

    myLoop();
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

So how do I set a hyperlink after a cleartimeout. I tried just before clearTimeout statement still not working. Actually, I have to show this anchor tag inside a division which redirects the division to given hyperlink after counter timeout.

Comment: `document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML() = "<a id='hi'href='page.html'>click</a>"` is syntactically incorrect. `keepGoing` is never used. `if(clearTimeout(timer))` doesn’t make sense, since `clearTimeout` doesn’t return anything. Why are you setting `document.getElementById("days").textContent`, then its `innerText` right after it? Or using the same `if` condition twice in a row? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: I've made necessary changes to the above code but can't get the redirection done through anchor tag.